# Writing (mixed) tensors

Tags: math-mode, packages, subscripts, superscripts

Does anybody know about a specific package for handling tensors? Consider, for example, a contraction of the type

```
$g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\gamma\delta}R_{\alpha\mu\gamma\nu}=R^{\beta\;delta}_{\;\mu\;\nu}$
```

Handling the indices in the mixed tensor in the r.h.s. appears particularly annoying and the result is not aesthetically satisfying. Any suggestion?

Comment: How about [the tensor package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tensor)

Comment: It may be possible to devise/construct a macro to typeset things to your liking, but that requires some more information. For instance, do you have an example of what an aesthetically satisfying/pleasing tensor handling looks like?

Comment: Perhaps the [tensind](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensind) package could be useful.

Comment: Werner: I think the tensor package pointed by Peter is satisfying. Gonzalo, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is the result you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\gamma\delta}R_{\alpha\mu\gamma\nu}=R^{\beta\;\delta}_{\;\mu\;\nu}$

$g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\gamma\delta}R_{\alpha\mu\gamma\nu}
    =\tensor{R}{^\beta_\mu^\delta_\nu}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it...

Answer (score 0):

I have defined a new command `\newcommand{\tenmix}[3]{{#1}^{#2}_{#3}}` where
`#1` is the tensor name, `#2` the contravariant indices and `#3` the covariant indices.

But I can't choose the order among the covariant and contravariant index, however it is not necessary to type the signs of superscript and subscript `^` and `_`. For example, the Riemann tensor: `\tenmix{R}{\lambda}{\mu \nu \rho}`

Comment: The problem with this is that it does not automatically handle the alignment of tensorial indices, which is key in physics for example, so we fall back to the problem of having to manually insert blanks to sort them. Employing the `tensor` package seems the best option.